# Canada Visa Rejection, needing Advice on Documentation

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens

Ok My story goes like this,
I got a VISA refusal for TRV (Temporary residence Visa ) for Canada with this Letter

[image: 12.png]

Now I did not include an Itenerary, Neither did I add a letter of Explanation, It seems like those two messed up the application big time.

I included the following,

- Letter for Employment
- Leave approval Letter
- Payslips for 4 months
- Company Registration Documents (Supported with affidavit)
- Passport Bio Data Page (As Requested)
- Hotel Reservation confirmation
- Stated that I am in Civil Union with a lady, and she would not be accompanying me to Canada first time as she is currently running a course in a University here in Nigeria.

**Possible Resolution**

I plan on submitting again, But the only travel history I have at this point is the travel history for W.African Nations, I now need your advice, Since I am going as a tourist, asides adding an **itinerary** as well as **letter of Explanation**, are there other documents I might need to add as a tourist? As included in the new itinerary that I would be visiting a Family friend who stays in Grand Prairie and Totonto, Do I need to have a Letter of invitation from them? Pls I need advices.

Comment: What job are you employed at, and with what kind of company? Why did you include company registration documents? Did you include document supporting your civil union? How long were you planning on visiting Canada for? Did you include financial and bank statements?

Comment: I did all. and i am planning on visiting for a week

Comment: What job are you employed at, and with what kind of company? Why did you include company registration documents?

Comment: I work as a software developer for a Bank and I also have a registered business which I run as well. hence I included the two of them, as i earn income from both

Comment: Based on the stated refusal reasons it seems unlikely that an itinerary and/or a letter would have helped much, unfortunately.

Comment: @jcm, kindly explain why you see it so

Comment: @Robert Paragraph 179(b) of the IRPR is a section of Canada's Immigration and Refugee Protection Regulations that allows visa officers to reject applications on the suspicion the applicant might try to stay in Canada beyond their temporary stay. Making a fresh application where the only change in your circumstances is mention of visiting a family friend in Canada won’t change that suspicion. Unfortunately, as you’ll probably be aware, Nigeria is universally seen as a high immigration risk country.

Comment: @Robert see Traveller's answer here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151343/is-it-possible-to-use-a-letter-of-invitation-together-with-an-itinerary
1. They are not satisfied with your travel history. 2. They believe there's a significant chance you'll violate the terms of the visa. Neither itinerary not letter of explanation will help much with those.