# Proof of Relationship when Visiting a Friend in Canada

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens

So far I have been able to come thru with Documentation until I arrived at this one :- Proof of Relationship, I am going to visit a friend , after the tour, I am returning home.

How Can I show the visa officer that this is my friend. I do not have any documentation of him, I just included that I got a letter from him and seeing this proof of relationship, I am a bit confused. I Decided to ask on here to clear the air on that very issue.
How can I prove relationship in this case.

Comment: Guidance on this is available here https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/evidence-supporting-purpose-entry.html  and reading this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151343/is-it-possible-to-use-a-letter-of-invitation-together-with-an-itinerary  may help.

Comment: @Traveller, No just said I should upload the invitation letter, I have done that , but the place where i need to upload proof of ties is still very angry and wont let me submit the application. So I am thinking , maybe I reupload the invitation there

Comment: Did you choose tourism as the purpose of your visit? If the purpose of your visit is primarily to see your friend and they have sent you the relevant documentation along with their invitation, then your ‘proof of relationship’ is likely to be evidence that shows a genuine friendship. Eg when/how you met (eg photos of you together, visits to you by your friend), how often/how you communicate (screen shots of online chat, emails etc). What you provide will depend on the history of the friendship.

Comment: Ah!, that means I should go with the primary purpose as tourism as stated in the itinerary and make the visit to my friend secondary? Thats what you imply? But at the same time I do have invites from him too..

Comment: How long out of the total trip are you planning to spend actually visiting your friend? I suspect you may be thinking that it will strengthen your chance of getting a visa if you throw in all the possible variations of documentation. But having an invite from a friend doesn’t guarantee success, especially if it appears contrived.

Answer (score 1):

During the online application, you should have seen a question asking you if you have a proof of relationship with the host.

[image]

If you selected No, then it should not be required. If that is the case but it still demands a proof of relationship, contact technical support with the button "Report a Technical Issue", usually they'll get back to you within a few days.